# Why is shebang in python script being ignored when calling the script as an argument on docker-compose run line?

Tags: python, docker, shebang

I have a docker container. It contains a very simply python script. Here is what the `docker_compose.yml` file looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  my_container:
    image: my_container
    build: .
    entrypoint: "bash"
```

I start the container. And from inside the container, I run the script like this:

```
$ docker-compose run my_container
root@fe39e296c411:/# ls -altr test_script_dir/test_script_file.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 98 Dec  4 10:22 test_script_dir/test_script_file.py

root@a3c9c8ff3b55:/# cat test_script_dir/test_script_file.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
def main():
    print "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

root@a3c9c8ff3b55:/# test_script_dir/test_script_file.py
Hello World
```

But I want to start this container and run this script in a single command. When I try to do it though, it errors out:

```
docker-compose run my_container test_script_dir/test_script_file.py
test_script_dir/test_script_file.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test_script_dir/test_script_file.py: line 2: `def main():'
```

It looks like the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` is being ignored instead of executed when I try to invole the script by passing it in as a command tacked on at the end of `docker-compose run`. Why? How can I get this to work? Is some environment variable not getting set?

Comment: What's the `ENTRYPOINT` in the container?

Comment: @johrsharpe, I edited the question to show my `docker_compose.yml` file. `entrypoint: "bash"`

Comment: There you go, `docker-compose run my_container test_script_dir/test_script_file.py` is the same as starting the container then running `bash test_script_dir/test_script_file.py` - it's *not* the same as executing the file directly as a script, the shebang isn't used.